# Jquery Sortable elements get "stuck" during sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a situation here, where I have to sort for dom elements where users can sort the elements.In some cases when sorting when I try to drop it in the desired position it gets stuck like below.

[image]

Below is the code that I am using for the sorting.

```
 $(sortableSelector).sortable({
    placeholder: "sc-highlight",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    cursorAt: { top: 25, left: 25 },
    connectWith: connectWithItem,
    handle: ".scw-move",
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    refreshPositions: true,
    revert: 450,
    items: sortableItems,
    //cancel: '.sce-redactor-init',
    start: function (event, ui) {

        ui.helper.addClass('started-sorting');
        ui.item.addClass('started-sorting');
        var startedSCPPanel1 = $(ui.helper).closest('div[class^="scp-panel"]');
        startedSCPPanel=startedSCPPanel1;
    },
    change: function () {
        console.log('asdf');
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.removeClass('started-sorting');           
    },
    beforeStop:function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).attr( "src", "replacement.png" );
    }
});
```

Both "stop" & "beforeStop" events are not triggered in some cases. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It would be alot easier for us to help you, if you created snippet that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen you mean a working a sample? if so i tried to replicate the same thing in the fiddle but i was not able to reproduce this.

Comment: That usually means there isn't a problem with this script, there's another script disturbing this code. Do you have any other JqueryUI plugins?

Comment: @RichardMuthwill no we use only jqueryUI

Comment: @SoftwareNerd then that suggests you have not presented the entire code in this post. Please update your post and ensure that you include all the code used and the specific library versions you are using for both jQuery and jQuery UI. It might also be CSS Related, so please include that too.